# KendoUI Remote datasource : assign url parameter a value from javascript variable

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using KendoUI to create charts from a remote datasource which is JSON file.
When I assign the  `url` parameter(inside datasource object) a remote path ,pointing to the JSON  the chart doesn't appear .

Say Like,

```
var myVar="some remote url"; 

dataSource: {
   transport: {
     read: {
       url: myVar,
       dataType: "json"
     }
   }
}
```

On the other hand if I directly specify the url as:

```
url: "http://myserver-name/somefile.json"
```

I can see the chart being displayed.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It should work! Check the following running on  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/7fVpW/2/).

```
var url = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products";
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }
    },
    pageSize: 4,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "ProductID",
            fields: {
                ProductID: {
                    editable: false,
                    nullable: true
                },
                ProductName: "ProductName"
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#kendogrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
        {
            field: "ProductID",
            title: "ID"},
        {
            field: "ProductName",
            title: "Name"}
    ]
});​
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="kendogrid"></div>​
```

It defines an external URL and sets it to a variable ( `url`) and then uses the resulting `DataSource`.

Check for differences or post a code as complete as possible in jsfiddle or jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

well , your solution worked for me but in different way.I was getting the url value from a .cs file and storing inside an javascript variable.
var URL="<%=myCSvariable%>";

But this alone doesnt works...:(
I had to modifiy the URL variable value  as,
var completeURL="\"" + URL + "\"";

and then create dataSource object as,

```
var mydataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
         transport: {
             read: {
                 url: URL,   // this is the tricky part. Using 'completeURL'           here doesnt creates my chart , instead 'URL' works just fine.
                 dataType: "json"
             }
         }


 });
```

I know its STRANGE but that's how it worked for me..
Anyways, Thanks a ton..:)